# not able to execute a compiled file - "permission denied"

Tags: compiling

I've compiled my file using the following command

```
gcc -o rget rget.c filerpc_clnt.c filerpc_xdr.c -Insl
```

I find that the file property "Allow files to be executed as program" is not enabled.

and so when i tried to execute i'm getting the permission denied message

```
./rget localhost mytestfile.txt
bash: ./rget: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Comments answered by OP`]

> The problem with that executable files is that it was in the windows formatted drive... so i moved that to the home directory and then executed the following command `chmod +x rget` and now i'm able to execute it. Thanks for all your support

Answer (score 3):

try to do a `chmod a+x rget` to activate the execution permission.
If the file is on NTFS or FAT, you have to change mounting options in fstab

Comment: I tried what you said, but still i face the same issue.

Comment: The problem with that executable files is that it was in the windows formatted drive...

so i moved that to the home directory and then executed the following command

chmode +x rget

and now i'm able to execute it.

Thanks for all your support